Freestyle lines are not fully shown / not visible
Does anyone know why all the outline options I try in blender have this same effect.
When I look at the object from the front view some lines are not shown.
I actually need the lines in front to be shown as well.
In the example down I used the freestyle outline option (because I needs an quick fix in multiple viewpoints)


You may notice, that the outline occurs where ever a sharp edge is located or it's needed to seperate visually overlapping parts like on the left and right side of the mesh in yor image.  What exactly are you needing this for? is it just for refrence when modeling?
